# Querying a table with an additional column containing table name

Tags: sql-server

- List item

I am looking for a way query to query a table and add a column with the table name, without explicitly writing the actual 'tablename' within the select statement. Is there a way to do this?

For example I want;
Table name: Construction
The original columns would be Modif_num, modif_desc.

I'd like a query with these results;

The original columns would be Modif_num, modif_desc.

```
MODIF_NUM   TABLE_NAME        MODIF_DESC  
2           Construction      Quality  
2           Construction      Quality  
2           Construction      Quality  
2           Construction      Quality
```

A regular select * would yield

```
MODIF_NUM   MODIF_DESC  
2           Quality  
2           Quality  
2           Quality  
2           Quality
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense (to me). `SELECT * FROM table WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Construction'` would give your example data. Perhaps you should write the query you've tried, that isn't working out so we can tell from where you're going wrong, what's wrong with your thinking. e.g. `SELECT FROM @myTableNameParameter WHERE blah = 'blah'` - simple answer is no, you can't parameterize a table name, unless you dynamically build sql in a string and EXEC it

Comment: To be honest I am a bit stuck. I'm aware I can find TableName from sys.tables, but aside from that I have no clue how I can join that table or add something to the query that can simply pull the table name.

Comment: There is nothing like reflection from dotnet or something like that to just magically return the table from a query. What would it return if there was a join in your query? To be honest your question is rather strange. Why do you need this column???

Comment: I have over ~30 tables in a DB with the same column structures and need to collate them into one table. However, would like to store the table names without having to write out 'ExampleTableName' each time I do an insert.

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you can return a column based on a string, for example:

```
SELECT 'Construction' As Table_Name, MODIF_NUM FROM  MyTable
```

OR

```
SELECT 'Construction' As Table_Name, * FROM  MyTable
```

To bring them together, a UNION may work:

```
SELECT 'Construction' As Table_Name,  MODIF_NUM, MODIF_DESC FROM  tblConstruction
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Demolition' As Table_Name,  MODIF_NUM, MODIF_DESC FROM  tblDemolition
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Reconstruction' As Table_Name,  MODIF_NUM, MODIF_DESC FROM  tblReconstruction
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

In this instance i would use excel.

column A : table name

column B : `="select cast('"&A1&"' as nvarchar(50)) as tablename ,* into TARGETTABLE from "& A1`

[image]

Then fill column A with all your table names.. then copy and paste column B into SSMS

This assumes based on your comment this is a one off task. If its not a one off task use the same logic to generate a bunch of strings and execute them.

Ah Wait sorry you cannot do select into repeatedly, what am i thinking.. sorry more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, a.*
  FROM [Construction] a,
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```